# How to call 2 functions after the setState is called in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, callback

I have to call 2 functions just after the `setState` is updated.
I want to use callback Function.
But the problem is one function is present in the current component and the other function I am calling of the child component(using refs).
The code looks something like this:

```
  handleChange_First = (event) => {
    

    const name = event.target.name;
   
    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value
    },() => {this.calculate()});
    this.child.handleChange(event)
   }
```

I want to call `this.calculate()` and `this.child.handleChange(event)`, as soon as the `setState` is changed.
Right now it is updating the value of the current component (this.calculate) but the value of the child component (handleChange) is not updating.

Or if there is any alternative way to call both the functions simultaneously just after the `setState`, that will also be very helpful.

Comment: Is the child component's handleChange not executing or it doesn't update the value?

Comment: The child component is executing but taking the previous value of from the current component rather than the updated value.(for example you enter 1 in current component it will not change anything in the child but when you enter 2, child component will take 1 and so on)

Answer (score 2):

Enter the second function call into the callback function body.
Try this:

```
handleChange_First = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;

        this.setState({[name]: event.target.value},() => {
                this.calculate();
                this.child.handleChange(event);
              });
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it throws error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined.
this error is because of this.child.handleChange(event).

Answer (score 2):

React uses a synthetic event pattern. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

This is the same reason, you are not able to use `event` in the callback. (`setState` is async, the reason you had to use callback in the first place)

There is an escape hatch though, you can ask React not to pool the event by calling `event.persist()`

```
handleChange_First = (event) => {
  event.persist();
  const name = event.target.name;

  this.setState({[name]: event.target.value},() => {
     this.calculate();
     this.child.handleChange(event);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are really a life saver :)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to call by a setTimeout, which will execute the function independently.

```
handleChange_First = (event) => {

    const name = event.target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value
    },() => {this.calculate()});

    setTimeOut(()=>{
      this.child.handleChange(event);
    })
   }
```

Comment: It throws this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null.